# Filter mongodb data by user

Tags: angular, mongodb, typescript, devexpress, devextreme

I have a collection of band data and users at `mongodb`. **What I want to do is:** the band data contains data such as `'band: band 1', 'band: band 2', 'band: band 3'`. (There are other data, but I wrote what I want to use).

I wanted the user to enter the band data when registering to find out which band was the user when registering. **When displaying data:** I want the user to show the tape if the band data is equal to the band. I want to do a sort of filtering process. I want to do the listing process that way. Could you help?

In this way I'm listing the band data:

```
refreshLineList() {
  this.lineService.getLineList().subscribe(res => {
      this.lineService.lines = res as Line[]; //Line = band data
      console.log(res);
  });
}
```

To attract user data:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.refreshLineList();
    this.userService.getUserProfile().subscribe(
      res => {
        this.userDetails = res['user'];
        console.log(res);
      },
      err => {
        console.log(err);
      }
    );
  }
```

user's console output:

```
> {status: true, user: {…}}
status: true 
user:
 bant: "Bant 1"  // **this is the part I should use in my filter**
 email: "e@e.com" > 
>  fullName: "esra"
> __proto__: Object
> __proto__: Object
```

Output of band data to console:

```
(4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0:
bant: "Bant 1"  // **this is the part I should use in my filter**
bantKisiSayisi: 2
calisilanToplamSure: 2
devamsizlikYuzdesi: 11.11111111111111
diger: 2
hatVerimliligi: 1
hataOrani: 200
ikinciKaliteAdedi: 2
ikinciKaliteOrani: 50
ilaveCalisilanDk: 2
ilaveCalisma: 0.06666666666666667
isKazasi: 2
iseGelmeyenlerinToplamSuresi: 2
koliCikisAdedi: 2
planlamayaUyum: 100
planlananAdet: 2
ramakKala: 2
sam: 2
sevkiyattanGelenHata: 2
tamirAdedi: 2
tarih: "2019-02-20T08:03:40.935Z"
__v: 0
_id: "5c6ac88edb48bf3850eebc75"
__proto__: Object
1: {_id: "5c6ac8acdb48bf3850eebc76", bant: "Bant 2", isKazasi: 0, ramakKala: 0, tamirAdedi: 2, …}
2: {_id: "5c6b14973eade027f4083dc4", bant: "Bant 1", isKazasi: 2, ramakKala: 0, tamirAdedi: 88, …}
3: {_id: "5c6d1ca109b191294856dcf9", bant: "Bant 3", isKazasi: 0, ramakKala: 0, tamirAdedi: 80, …}
length: 4
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem you are trying to solve? I just do not understand where you need help. Please provide a small sample document that clearly points out the problem and either the error message you are seeing or the query/transformation you are trying to run.

Comment: Let me give you an example. you have a database. There are 2 collections in the database. they are: line and user data.
in line collection; id, date, 'line no', number of work accidents etc. holds the data. (There are 7 lines)
user collection; id, user name, email, password and 'line no' data are kept.
I'm working on these. what i want to do is:

Comment: if the line number of the user is equal to the line number of the line data, list the data of that line on the display.
that is, when the line 1 user logs in, the line 1 user's data should appear from the line data.
if admin logs in, they can see all line data.

Comment: I don't get it. Could you perhaps provide a reproducible sample that shows your problem? An example of the input data, your desired output, what you've tried perhaps and what you observed or details about what exactly doesn't work.

Comment: actually I don't have an error in the middle I just want to make the user limitation. ie filtering process. but I don't know how to do it. So in my question I've listed the code I've listed all my data on.